# Undefined control sequences \@kernel@after@para@end and \@kernel@after@para@after

Tags: compiling, paragraphs, compilation-error

I have a .tex file that compiles without problems on my laptop (Windows 10).

I am now using a different computer (also Windows 10) and I synced the file using Dropbox. (I don't know if this is relevant.)

On that computer, it does not compile. I have tried TeXworks, TeXstudio, Texmaker and the result is the same. I get

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> <argument> ...n {para/end}\@kernel@after@para@end

or

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> <argument> ...ara/after}\@kernel@after@para@after

at the end of every paragraph, at every `\section`, every `\item` and every `\begin` and `\end` of all environments.

What in the world is going on? A corrupted MiKTeX installation? I don't think it is an encoding problem because it persists when I remove newline characters and it also happens with the following code that I wrote on that computer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have somehow installed code expecting the most recent latex release on a system with an older latex

Comment: perhaps you installed a new firstaid version, but didn't update latex.

Comment: You mention MikTeX, so I might as well throw in the standard MikTeX comment: If you have installed MikTeX as admin you have to update your system in both Admin and User mode to make sure that you have compatible package versions. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864. Just run an update from the Console in user mode and then again in Admin mode. (I tested your code on a fully updated MikTeX and it compiles fine.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If I understand correctly I need to update MiKTeX. If I update it in user mode only it causes an out of sync error. And I don't have admin powers on that computer, so I think the situation is hopeless.